# How to Run SharePoint Online PowerShell scripts on VSTS

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, azure-devops, office365, sharepoint-online

I need to execute SharePoint Online PowerShell scripts from VSTS Build.

In the case of local machine, we use the below to execute SharePoint Online PowerShell scripts which create lists, etc..

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
```

I guess we need to replace the above with the below

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell
```

in the powershell task of the build.

Cmdlets of *Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell* refers to files in the folder **C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell** in local machine.

How do I refer to SharePoint Online Management Shell files, and execute the PowerShell scripts in VSTS build task which create site columns, lists etc.. on SharePoint Online?

Comment: What's the problem with the original way to do with SharePoint Online? There are the script samples: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-create-a-List-in-a-2ff75523  and https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2014/02/18/office-365-powershell-script-to-create-a-list-add-fields-and-change-the-default-view-all-using-csom/

Comment: Setup a private agent on your machine and try with that script and check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup a private agent at one of your network machines. Then install the required dependencies on it. This should work.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts to see how to do it.